# Why does pandas groupby().transform() require a unique index?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use groupby().transform() to do a custom (cumulative) transform of each block of records in a (sorted) dataset.  Unless I ensure I have a unique key, it doesn't work.  Why?

Here's a toy example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1],
                  [1,2],
                  [2,3],
                  [3,4],
                  [3,5]], 
                  columns='a b'.split())
df['partials'] = df.groupby('a')['b'].transform(np.cumsum)
df
```

gives the expected:

```
     a   b   partials
0    1   1   1
1    1   2   3
2    2   3   3
3    3   4   4
4    3   5   9
```

but if 'a' is a key, it all goes wrong:

```
df = df.set_index('a')
df['partials'] = df.groupby(level=0)['b'].transform(np.cumsum)
df

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-146-d0c35a4ba053> in <module>()
      3 
      4 df = df.set_index('a')
----> 5 df.groupby(level=0)['b'].transform(np.cumsum)

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.pyc in transform(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
   1542             res = wrapper(group)
   1543             # result[group.index] = res
-> 1544             indexer = self.obj.index.get_indexer(group.index)
   1545             np.put(result, indexer, res)
   1546 

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.pyc in get_indexer(self, target, method, limit)
    847 
    848         if not self.is_unique:
--> 849             raise Exception('Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index '
    850                             'objects')
    851 

Exception: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

Same error if you select column 'b' before grouping, ie.

```
df['b'].groupby(level=0).transform(np.cumsum)
```

but you can make it work if you transform the entire dataframe, like:

```
df.groupby(level=0).transform(np.cumsum)
```

or even a one-column dataframe (rather than series):

```
df.groupby(level=0)[['b']].transform(np.cumsum)
```

I feel like there's some still some deep part of [GroupBy-fu](http://wesmckinney.com/blog/?p=125) that I'm missing.  Can someone set me straight?

Comment: Yes, it is what I want - the partial sums of 'b' within groups of 'a'.  I clarified the illustration above.  In my actual example, 'a' is a timestamp and b are some other keys, so my dataset is actually a collection of time series of different lengths (which overlap in time and contain duplicate timestamps within and across groups).  I'm using transform() to do cumulative operations on each time series segment like moving averages and so on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a bug, since fixed in pandas (certainly in 0.15.2, IIRC it was fixed in 0.14), so you should no longer see this exception.

---

As a workaround, in earlier pandas you can use [apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#flexible-apply):

```
In [10]: g = df.groupby(level=0)['b']

In [11]: g.apply(np.cumsum)
Out[11]:
a
1    1
1    3
2    3
3    4
3    9
dtype: int64
```

and you can assign this to a column in df

```
In [12]: df['partial'] = g.apply(np.cumsum)
```

Comment: Cool, thanks - I guess I don't understand the difference between apply() and transform() then.  Is transform somehow more restrictive??

Comment: @patricksurry I'm wondering if it's a bug, it certainly looks like it should fit in the transform category...

Comment: @patricksurry tranform expects one result to all the things in the group, whereas apply expects a value for each row in the group. Although both act of the groups (sub DataFrames) so it is a little confusing.

Comment: That makes sense, but doesn't seem to be very clearly documented.  For example [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html) it starts by describing transform as a form of apply, and later makes them sound almost equivalent: "... For these, use the apply function, which can be substituted for both aggregate and transform in many standard use cases. However, apply can handle some exceptional use cases, for example..."